# Reproduce the behaviour of strcpy

Tags: c, strcpy

I'm trying to reproduce the behaviour of `strcpy` in c, my problem is that the function works but it append extra stuff at the end.

```
char    *ft_strcpy(char * dst, const char * src)
{
int i;
i = 0;
while (src[i] != '\0') {
    dst[i] = src[i];
    i++;
}
return dst;
}
```

When i run it I get the following.

```
int main()
{
char p[] = {};
char z[] = "Hello World";
ft_strcpy(p,z);
printf("%s\n", p);
return 0;
}
```

[function results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvr8R.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't copying the nul terminator so the `printf` doesn't know to stop.

Just add `dst[i] = 0;` after the loop.

Also, you haven't allocated any space for `p`, so you're going to get undefined behavior. For a first test just do something like `char p[100];` and make sure `z` is never > 99 chars long. Eventually you need a better fix, but that will get you started.

Comment: Yes, thanks but I still get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` text.

Comment: Did you address the fact that `p` doesn't have "space"?

Comment: Ok, I used your suggestion and its working. I just need a way to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

TenTen,

Set dest[i] to '\0' after ending the loop. Here is the code:

```
int main()
    {
    char src[100], dest[100], i;
    printf("Enter string Src: ");
    scanf("%s",src);
    for(i=0; src[i]!='\0'; ++i)
        {
        dest[i]=src[i];
        }
    dest[i]='\0';
    printf("String Dest: %s",dest);
    return 0;
    }
```